# Overriding an abstract property with a derived return type in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding, abstract, derived

I have four classes.  Request, DerivedRequest, Handler, DerivedHandler.  The Handler class has a property with the following declaration:

```
public abstract Request request { get; set; }
```

The DerivedHandler needs to override this property so that it returns DerivedRequest instead:

```
public override DerivedRequest request { get; set; }
```

Does anyone have any ideas about how to make this work?

Comment: This is not strictly good OOP, as it violates the interface.  Some types of setter operations (with non-dervied `value`s) will throw unexpectedly.

Comment: In this case, I suppose, I wouldn't need a setter.  I could make a private property and set it in the constructor.  That would take care of setter operation exceptions, yes?

Comment: In that case, you wouldn't need to override the property.  Just have the constructor only accept the DerivedRequest.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This isn't really a good way to structure things. Do one of the following

1) Just don't change the return type, and override it normally in the subclass. In `DerivedHandler` you can return an instance of `DerivedRequest` using the base class signature of `Request`. Any client code using this can choose to cast it to `DerivedRequest` if they want to.

2) Use generics instead if they are not supposed to be polymorphic.

```
public abstract class HandlerBase<T> where T: Request
{
    public abstract T Request {get;set;}
}

public class Handler: HandlerBase<Request>()

public class DerivedHandler: HandlerBase<DerivedRequest>()
```

Comment: If there is multiple cases, such as several properties that I want to override in a such way that they use derived classes, then I need to do something like `class HandlerBase<A,B,C,..> where A:classA, B:classB,...` ?

Answer (score 6):

In the C# language you are **not allowed to change the signature of an inherited method, unless you substitute it with another method with the same name**. This technique is referred to as "member hiding" or "shadowing".

If you are using .NET 2.0 or later, you could solve this problem by turning the return type of the `Request` property into a generic type parameter of the `Handler` class. The `DerivedHandler` class would then specify the `DerivedRequest` class as argument for that type parameter.

Here's an example:

```
// Handler.cs
public class Handler<TRequest> where TRequest : Request
{
    public TRequest Request { get; set; }
}

// DerivedHandler.cs
public class DerivedHandler : Handler<DerivedRequest>
{
}
```

Comment: You certainly can do so; nothing in "OOP" forbids you from doing so as long as the Liskov Substitution Principle is maintained. For example, in the object oriented language "C++" it is legal to override a method that returns an Animal with one that returns a Tiger. This feature is called "return type covariance" and it is fairly common in OOP languages. It is not a feature of C# though.

Comment: @Eric Lippert You're absolutely right. I'm familiar with _return type covariance_ and _parameter type contravariance_. C# has supported it for delegate types since 1.0. Later C# 4.0 added support for generic interfaces and delegate types as well. Thanks for pointing out my mistake, I corrected the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Except for hiding the original property:

```
public new DerivedRequest Request { get;set;}
```

However, I strongly advise against that. Hiding something supposed to be overriden is inviting trouble, especially if the property isn't a simple auto generated one. Also, if using it as an interface or base class, the original implementation (in that case, one class higher in the inheritance tree). If you are implementing an abstract class or interface, you won't even be able to hide the original signature, as you are required to implement it.

Usually, if you think about using the `new` keyword, you are on the wrong track. There are cases where it is necessary and required, however, in most cases, it isn't.

Instead, make another property:

```
public DerivedRequest DerivedRequest {/* make adequate conversions here*/ }
```

That way, you are on the clear side concerning OOP and you get your information in a clear way.

Comment: Well, how would you handle setter?

Comment: Any `DerivedRequest` is still a `Request` further down and can be directly assigned.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
You can't change the type on a derived type, but `new` might help:

In the derived type...

```
public new DerivedRequest request
{
   get{return (DerivedRequest) base.request;}
   set{base.request = value;}
}
public override Request request
{
   get{return base.request;}
   set{base.request = (DerivedRequest) value;} // Throws InvalidCastException if misused.
}
```

Comment: this is not usually called "override"

Answer (score 0):

This is not theoretically possible. The override must be covariant for return type (that is, the return type must be more specific or the same), and contravariant for parameter (that is, parameter type must be less specific or the same). So your new type must be effectively at the same time covariant and contravariant with respect to the `Request` -- that means, the only possible type is just `Request`.

For this reason, it's not allowed in C# to change the type of properties for overrides.

Comment: Wouldn't DerivedRequest be more specific than Request, and consequently make the override covariant for return type?  Or did I read your comment wrong?

Comment: @threed: a property consists of a getter and a setter. the problem is with the setter :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Request{}

public class DerivedRequest : Request{}

public class Handler<T>
  where T : Request
{
  public abstract T Request { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedHandler : Handler<DerivedRequest>
{
  public override DerivedRequest Request { get; set; }
}
```